# UIImageView fill in UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I have a `UIImageView` as a `subview` of `UIView` (frame size **300 x 300**). My `UIImage` would be either portrait, landscape or some odd sizes. How do I fill in the `UIImage` within the `UIView` frame size without stretching the image to **300 x 300**?

The purpose of this, I will be adding another `UIImageView` as the image border. 
Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try

`[img setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];`

> UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit: Scales the content to fit the size of the view by 
>   maintaining the aspect ratio. Any remaining area of the view’s bounds is transparent.

or `[img setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];`

> UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill: Scales the content to fill the size of the view. Some 
>   portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.

if you are clipping subviews, then you need to do

```
[imgView clipToBounds:YES];
```

Comment: i tried to use the above 2 modes, my image does not fit in 300 x 300

Comment: ivEditImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:imgChoosen]; ivEditImage.frame = vwEditingImage.frame; [ivEditImage setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill];

Comment: even `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` doesnt do it?

Comment: if you are clipping subviews, then you need to do `[imgView clipToBounds:YES];`

Answer (score 2):

Ah I just reread what you were asking, I know what your question is now.

Your `UIImageView`'s frame changes, and when it does so does your image. You don't want your image to change, but you do want your `ImageView` to adjust to fill the view it is contained in.

UPDATE

I figured it out.

```
[self.imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
```

No matter what orientation, the size stays the same.

You also have the option of setting it to align top, bottom, left, right, top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right, all of which only help to align your image and NOT redraw or re-size the image.

Does that help?

Comment: if i redraw, it will stretch my image. Is there any option not to stretch?

Answer (score 1):

```
 [image setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the contentMode property of `UIImageView` to either of this values depending on where you want to put it in the superview:

```
 UIViewContentModeCenter,
    UIViewContentModeTop,
    UIViewContentModeBottom,
    UIViewContentModeLeft,
    UIViewContentModeRight,
    UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
    UIViewContentModeTopRight,
    UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
    UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
```

As this values:

```
UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
    UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
```

Will indeed cause the image to be 300 x 300, which is what you don't want.

Comment: Is there a way to combine them? What I want is this: assume a image of 100x10 and a full screen UIImageView. I want it to expand until the horizontal size is equal to the UIImageView width (say 320 for the iPhone) and the resulting image (now at 320x32) to be at the top . I tried this imgview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit | UIViewContentModeTop; but it does not work. It just does the UIViewContentModeTop part (100x10 at the top).

Comment: @Gik - Did you find any way to do that. I am having the exact same problem.

Comment: I did it using a trick. I "created" another image (from the original), stretched to fill the smaller size and then padded with the pixels I was "missing". So at the end I got a 300x300 image from the original. If you want I could post the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use the contentMode property of UIImageView.

---

**Edit:** and set the image size to **300x300**.